# Access VBA pass-through query connection string update doesn't work

Tags: ms-access, vba

Afternoon all,

I have a simple problem that has me stumped. I am trying to change the connection strings for my pass-though queries. My issue is, it seems to work. The connection strings do get updated to the new connection string, however, when I run it, it is clearly using the previous connection string.

Code:

```
Sub UpdatePassthroughConnecStrings()
    Dim qdf As QueryDef

    For Each qdf In CurrentDb.QueryDefs
        If qdf.Type = dbQSQLPassThrough Then
            qdf.Connect = ConnectString
        End If
    Next qdf

End Sub

Function ConnectString() As String
    Dim strYear As String

    strYear = "LIMS" & Form_frm_Main.Year
    ConnectString = "ODBC;DSN=LIMS;UID=" & strYear & ";PWD=1234;"

End Function
```

Basically, I am updated the UID portion so I can connect to the correct Oracle db tablespace (it's split by year). When I check the connection strings after the update it is correctly updated but just doesn't connect correctly. Interestingly, this code works in Excel just fine. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Sounds like a connection is getting reused/not getting torn down completely/correctly. Connection pool behavior issue, possibly?

Comment: That's a pretty good guess, not sure how I would flush the pool from within Access though

Comment: Well, at first blush it seems like a bit of a kluge, but if you're changing the connection string you could explicitly Close the querydef just before the ConnectionString update...purely a stab in the dark.

Comment: What you have looks just fine. I would add after changing the querydefs, try  Currentdb.QueryDefs.Refresh. The comments here about the previous connection remaining active is correct, but as long as the new connection is valid and they can connect to the active server, then the new connection(s) should work. give the above refresh command a try.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I added the above Currentdb.QueryDefs.Refresh to my code but the problem still persists. The connection string clearly is updated but is still connecting to original connection string.

Comment: and if you change the connectionstring manually on the property sheet, does it work?

Comment: no it doesn't work if I change it manually

Comment: Are your queries updating linked tables? Are you looking for the results of the query actions in Oracle or Access?

Comment: No they aren't updating linked tables, in fact this front end has no linked tables. The only thing that works is to run the function, change the connection string, close access db, reopen it and the pass-through queries now query the proper tablespace.